# why can't pass file path argument to shell command 'more' in pipeline mode?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, pipeline

I have a text file a.txt

```
hello world
```

I use following commands:

cmd1:

```
$ more a.txt
```

```
output:

hello world
```

cmd2:

```
$ echo 'a.txt'|more
```

```
output:

a.txt
```

I thought cmd2 should equal to `echo 'a.txt'|xargs -i more {}`，but it's not.

I want to know why cmd2 worked like that and how to write code which work differently in pipeline mode.

Comment: If `echo 'a.txt' | more` worked the way you expect, then `journalctl | more` *couldn't work*, because it would expect the output of `journalctl` to be a list of filenames, not the actual content to display.

Comment: That said, a general-purpose "how do UNIX semantics work?" question is a better fit for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), vs Stack Overflow.

Comment: Let's turn the tables. `echo foo | more` outputs `foo`, so why does `more foo` output the contents of a file named `foo` instead? The answer to both questions is: standard input and arguments are two completely different interfaces, addressing different use cases.

Comment: "I thought cmd2 should equal to echo 'a.txt'|xargs -i more {}".  Why did you think that?  If they were equivalent, then why would anyone use `xargs`?

Answer (score 1):

Redirection with `|` or `<` controls *what the stdin stream contains*; it has no impact on a program's command line argument list.

Thus, `more <a.txt` (efficiently) or `cat a.txt | more` (inefficiently) both attach a file handle from which one can read the contents of `a.txt` to the stdin file handle of a new process before replacing that process with `more`. Similarly, `echo a.txt | more` makes `a.txt` itself *the literal text* that `more` reads from its stdin stream, *which is the default place it's documented to get the input to display from, if not given any more specific filename(s) on its command line*.

---

Generally, if you have a list of filenames and want to convert them to command-line arguments, this is what `xargs` is for (though using it without a great deal of care can introduce bugs, potentially-security-impacting ones).

Consider the following, which (using NUL rather than newline delimiters to separate filenames) is a safe use of `xargs` to take a list of filenames being piped into it, and transform that into an argument list to `cat`, used to concatenate all those files together and generate a single stream of input to `more`:

```
printf '%s\0' a.txt b.txt |
  xargs -0 cat -- |
  more
```